# Pandas MultiIndex rearranging columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The MultiIndex rearranges the columns seemingly randomly when the label values are not aligned, when I use the function `get_level_values` to get the columns values.

For instance, I can create a MultiIndex, whose labels are ordered from 0 to 4.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
work_index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['ANA','ANC','PPI','SCAF','SAC'],['Sample']],labels=[[0,1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

When I put this MultiIndex into a dataframe and run the `get_levels_values` function I get `['ANA','ANC','PPI','SCAF','SAC']` in the proper order I expect to get.

```
work=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=work_index)
work.columns #note the proper order
>>> MultiIndex(levels=[['ANA', 'ANC', 'PPI', 'SCAF', 'SAC'], ['Sample']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
work.columns.get_level_values(0) #same order as before
>>> Index(['ANA', 'ANC', 'PPI', 'SCAF', 'SAC'], dtype='object')
```

However, if I create a multindex with the labels not in numerical order, `get_level_values` returns a weird, seemingly random order. Here instead of `[0,1,2,3,4]` I choose `[2,1,4,3,0]`.

```
not_work_index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['ANA','ANC','PPI','SCAF','SAC'],['Sample']],labels=[[2, 1, 4, 3, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Putting this into a dataframe does not give me `['ANA','ANC','PPI','SCAF','SAC']`, rather `['PPI','ANC','SAC','SCAF','ANA']`

```
not_work=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5),columns=not_work_index)
not_work.columns
>>> MultiIndex(levels=[['ANA', 'ANC', 'PPI', 'SCAF', 'SAC'], ['Sample']],
       labels=[[2, 1, 4, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
not_work.columns.get_level_values(0)
>>> Index(['PPI', 'ANC', 'SAC', 'SCAF', 'ANA'], dtype='object')
```

Is there a way for `get_level_values` to return the levels in order even if the labels are not in order? Is there another way to query the upper level to get the columns in correct order?

Comment: I haven't run your example but in general multi-indices need to be sorted in order for them to be useful

Comment: How would I sort a multindex then? When I read my csv in it creates these uneven labels

Comment: I'm not sure if this a bug or not, it seems that when you get the level values it's always sorted but that the index object knows the created order, if you wanted to get the actual insertion order you have to do something gnarly like this: `In [11]:

not_work.columns.get_level_values(0)[not_work.columns.labels[0]]
Out[11]:
Index(['SAC', 'ANC', 'ANA', 'SCAF', 'PPI'], dtype='object')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, it looks like `get_level_values` always returns a sorted array ignoring the creation order, the `IndexArray` itself knows the correct order. You can get the order you want using the following gnarly code to get the `label` array to mask the level values:

```
In [11]:
not_work.columns.get_level_values(0)[not_work.columns.labels[0]]

Out[11]:
Index(['SAC', 'ANC', 'ANA', 'SCAF', 'PPI'], dtype='object')
```

Here I access the `labels` attribute of the `IndexArray` or columns:

```
In [12]:
not_work.columns.labels

Out[12]:
FrozenList([[2, 1, 4, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I then index the first level using `[0]`:

```
In [13]:
not_work.columns.labels[0]

Out[13]:
FrozenNDArray([2, 1, 4, 3, 0], dtype='int8')
```

We can then use this to mask the level values to return the original order:

```
In [11]:
not_work.columns.get_level_values(0)[not_work.columns.labels[0]]

Out[11]:
Index(['SAC', 'ANC', 'ANA', 'SCAF', 'PPI'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I think this is a bug, but thank you for the workaround